# Makefile cause fatal error: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, c++17

I have problems with my makefile. Running it cause the error:

```
make
g++    -c -o vcd_converter.o vcd_converter.cpp
In file included from vcd_converter.cpp:2:
vcd_converter.h:16:10: fatal error: defs.h: No such file or directory
   16 | #include "defs.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: vcd_converter.o] Error 1
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
gui
-src
--main
---cpp
----agu.h 
----agu.cpp 
----vcd_converter.h 
----vcd_converter.cpp
----main_converter.cpp 
----makefile 
----.....
processor
-src
--main
---cpp
----defs.h
----defs.cpp
----argparser.h
----argparser.cpp
----util.h
```

And my makefile looks like this:

```
CC=g++
INCLUDE=-I. -I../../../../processor/src/main/cpp
CFLAGS=-std=c++17 -fconcepts -lstdc++fs -lpthread
DEPS = ../../../../processor/src/main/cpp/defs.h agu.h agu_mem.h    input_agu.h is_configurable.h is_steppable.h output_agu.h output_agu_mem.h pe.h vcd_converter.h ../../../../processor/src/main/cpp/util.h input_agu_mem.h ../../../../processor/src/main/cpp/argparser.h
OBJ = ../../../../processor/src/main/cpp/defs.o vcd_converter.o is_configurable.o is_steppable.o pe.o agu.o input_agu.o output_agu.o agu_mem.o input_agu_mem.o output_agu_mem.o ../../../../processor/src/main/cpp/argparser.o
%.o: %.c $(DEPS) $(INCLUDE)
    $(CC) -c  $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 
vcd_converter: ${OBJ} main_converter.cpp  $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -o vcd_converter ${OBJ} main_converter.cpp $(CFLAGS)
```

And running this I get the error from above. Have somebody an idea what is wrong here?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's look at the compile line make prints:

```
g++    -c -o vcd_converter.o vcd_converter.cpp
```

Now let's look at your rule:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS) $(INCLUDE)
         $(CC) -c  $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Given that we know the variable `INCLUDE` and `CFLAGS` are set, what can we understand from the fact that the compile line make prints bears no relationship to the compile line in your rule?

What we can understand is, your rule is clearly not being used by make.  If it was, we'd see your options in the command that make invokes.

So what rule is being used?  Make provides a number of built-in rules that it uses to create well-known targets.  These built-in rules use predefined variables (for C++, the compiler is kept in the `CXX` variable and the compiler flags are kept in the `CXXFLAGS` variable).  You can see a list of most of the built-in rules and variables here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

If you run `make -r` to disable the built-in rules, then instead of this odd compiler command make will complain that it can't find a rule to build `vcd_converter.o`.

Why isn't your rule being used?  Let's look again:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS) $(INCLUDE)
```

This says, for this pattern to apply (and hence for make to use it to build a .o file), both the `.c` file must exist *AND* all the files with names contained in the variables `DEPS` and `INCLUDE` must also exist.

So, first you're saying every `.o` file will be rebuilt whenever any header file changes.  Maybe that's true, and OK.

But you're also saying that every object file depends on the contents of `INCLUDE`, which is:

```
-I. -I../../../../processor/src/main/cpp
```

Make doesn't know anything about compiler flags: it will treat these *as file names*.  So, this pattern will only apply if make can find, or create, a file named literally `-I.`.  Which of course it can't, so this rule doesn't apply at all.

You can run `make -d` and see what make is considering and why it decides that a given rule is not acceptable.

So, if you change your pattern rule to:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
         $(CC) -c  $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

(remove the `INCLUDE` variable) you'll have much better luck.  There are, though, still some weird things about this: for example hopefully the incorrect `vcd_converter` rule is just a typo in your question.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. I tried this, but nothing changed.
And no, the vcd_converter rule is not just a typo...

Comment: Did you try running with `make -r`?  Did you get an error?  If nothing changed then one of the other dependencies you list must not exist: either one of the header files in `DEPS` or the file `vcd_converter.c` must not exist.  Run `make -r -d` and look at the output; it's long but it will tell you exactly which file was missing.

Comment: The rule you provide in your question for `vcd_converter` cannot be right, because you must have a newline/TAB before you start the recipe (`$(CC) ...`).  You cannot put the recipe on the same line as the target (unless you use a semicolon).  There isn't one in the makefile you pasted above.

Comment: When i running it with `make -r` i get the error message: `make: *** No rule to make target 'vcd_converter.o', needed by 'vcd_converter'.  Stop.`

Comment: Ok and the newline before the recipe i have in my makefile.. format problems by posting it here, sorry.

Comment: And make prints g++    `-c -o vcd_converter.o vcd_converter.cpp`. So my rule will not be used here too, and I don't know why,,

Comment: I said how to figure it out: you have to run `make -r -d` and look at the output.  make will explain every file it tries to find or build and whether it succeeded or not.  Find the prerequisite (`.h` etc.) that make can't find when it decides it doesn't know how to build `vcd_converter.o`.  We can't see your filesystem and what files exist or don't exist so we can't help.  Likely it's a path problem where you have listed an incorrect path to a file.